# How to programmatically set tab order

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, focus, tab-ordering

I am building a window from code.
I add a header TextBlock and then some various elements for a listBox in which each element is made out of 
Grid ---> children[0] a TextBlock to explain what is the element
     ---> children[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgF9o.png) a TextBox or combobox to input data.
At the end a button.

After having generated put the focus on the first element (generally the first TextBox) so that the user can immediately input data. Up to that everything works.

--ADD-- 
I forgot to mention that every element = Grid = Textblock + TextBox or combobox, is an element of the parent listBox. So I would like to move from every textbox or combobox independently from the listbox element they are in.

[image]

After that I want the user to be able to move to next element (textbox or combobox) through TAB. So when generating the previous windows I use a counter and set

```
tb.TabIndex = tabIndex++;
```

or
    ComboBox.TabIndex = tabIndex++;

Now the problem is that after having input data in the first TextBox when I press TAB the caret gets lost and so the focus...

---ADD2---
Here is the code:

```
 private void PreparareTraceFieldGrid(ListBox lbTracefields, ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, object, object>> obc, bool IsReadOnly)
 {
        bool IsFocusSet = false;
        /*---TITOLO---*/
        OutlinedTextBlock otbTitle = CreateOtbForTraceFieldInputWindow(Languages.Word(eWords.InsertTracefields));
        lbTracefields.Items.Add(otbTitle);
        /*----CICLO----*/
        int tabIndex = 0;
        foreach (var item in obc)
        {
            Grid gridInternal = new Grid();
            gridInternal.Background = Brushes.Transparent;

            ColumnDefinition cd1 = new ColumnDefinition();
            cd1.Width = new GridLength(300, GridUnitType.Pixel);
            ColumnDefinition cd2 = new ColumnDefinition();
            cd2.Width = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star);
            gridInternal.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd1);
            gridInternal.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd2);

            OutlinedTextBlock otb = CreateOtbForTraceFieldInputWindow(item.Item1);
            otb.FontSize = easyRunData.OptionsGraphical.FontSize;
            otb.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(easyRunData.OptionsGraphical.StrokeColour);
            otb.StrokeThickness = easyRunData.OptionsGraphical.StrokeSize;
            Grid.SetColumn(otb, 0);
            gridInternal.Children.Add(otb);

            string strDataType = item.Item2.ToString();
            eTraceFieldDataTypes eDataType = (eTraceFieldDataTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(eTraceFieldDataTypes), strDataType);

            switch (eDataType)
            {
                case eTraceFieldDataTypes.STRING:
                case eTraceFieldDataTypes.FLOAT:
                case eTraceFieldDataTypes.INTEGER:
                case eTraceFieldDataTypes.STRING_READONLY:
                    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                    tb.CaretBrush = Brushes.White;
                    tb.FontSize = easyRunData.OptionsGraphical.FontSize;
                    tb.MinWidth = 200;
                    tb.Height = easyRunData.OptionsGraphical.FontSize + 15;
                    tb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                    tb.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
                    tb.Margin = new Thickness(10);
                    tb.TabIndex = tabIndex++;
                    tb.KeyDown += (senderEvent, args) => { AnalyzeTraceFields_IF_EMPTY(easyRunData.Tracefields.TraceFieldsUser, (Grid)lbTracefields.Parent); };

                    if (eDataType == eTraceFieldDataTypes.STRING_READONLY && !IsReadOnly)
                        tb.BorderBrush = Brushes.Yellow;
                    else
                        tb.BorderBrush = Brushes.Gainsboro;
                    Grid.SetColumn(tb, 1);
                    gridInternal.Children.Add(tb);
                    lbTracefields.Items.Add(gridInternal);
                    if (!IsFocusSet)
                    {
                        tb.Focus();
                        IsFocusSet = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case eTraceFieldDataTypes.BOOL:
                case eTraceFieldDataTypes.BOOL_READONLY:
                    Border brd = new Border();
                    brd.Margin = new Thickness(10);
                    brd.MinWidth = 200;
                    brd.Height = easyRunData.OptionsGraphical.FontSize + 15;
                    if (eDataType == eTraceFieldDataTypes.BOOL_READONLY && !IsReadOnly)
                        brd.BorderBrush = Brushes.Yellow;
                    else
                        brd.BorderBrush = Brushes.Gainsboro;
                    brd.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3);
                    ComboBox cmb = new ComboBox();
                    cmb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                    cmb.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
                    cmb.Items.Add(Languages.Word(eWords.True));
                    cmb.Items.Add(Languages.Word(eWords.False));
                    cmb.BorderBrush = Brushes.Gainsboro;
                    cmb.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3);
                    cmb.Margin = new Thickness(0);
                    cmb.TabIndex = tabIndex++;
                    cmb.DropDownClosed += (senderEvent, args) => { AnalyzeTraceFields_IF_EMPTY(easyRunData.Tracefields.TraceFieldsUser, (Grid)lbTracefields.Parent); };
                    Grid.SetColumn(brd, 1);
                    brd.Child = cmb;
                    gridInternal.Children.Add(brd);
                    lbTracefields.Items.Add(gridInternal);
                    if (!IsFocusSet)
                    {
                        cmb.Focus();
                        IsFocusSet = true;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
}
```

Comment: I think it would help to see more code - less pretty picture. I get what you're trying to do, but, we need the code

Comment: Here is what you asked. Thanks

Comment: You should not use ListBox as parent, use StackPanel instead, which you can add items, but not make tab action so hard.

Comment: I have to use a listbox for it has the dinamic behaviour I need.

Comment: The worst case scenario is that I have to handle all that through focus and keydown action on a lambda expression